# Kotlin recyclerview adapter list objects are updated before setting the new list with those object updated?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I know that objects are referenced by memory, so when said object is modified, all places that reference that object will be affected.

I have a MutableMap<String, MyClass>, in which I load all the elements at the start of the app to have them more accessible. This map is LiveData, so I watch when I make changes to it and from another screen I am notified and update my RecyclerView after getting a new list with updated map objects.

The problem is that when modifying the values ​​of the properties of the mutablemap value, the recyclerview already has those new values, even before shaping the mutablemap to make a submitlist of the new list.

if i print the modified item of the recyclerview list before and after the submitlist, they both have the modified values, therefore diffutil doesn't work, unless you call:

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.itemCount)
```

but in that case it wouldn't make sense to use DiffUtil.
You could also pass the recyclerview as a parameter and with an extension function update only the visible items, but it's the same case.

This only happens by updating an item, if I add or delete it, the diffutil works and even those that had not been updated are updated

I already tried using `MyClass.copy()` and even created a function `newInstance(element: MyClass) = MyClass(element.property)`
, but it doesn't work, Even if I compare the memory address of object 1 of the recyclerview list with object 1 of the MutableMap with the === operator after doing newInstance to the MutableMap object, it returns false, but the data is still bound.

The only thing that worked for me is getting the same object from the database with its id, but obviously this is much slower, that's why I have everything preloaded in the MutableMap

or any other solution that can help me? tnks

Comment: Hello!  I think you'll need to reduce your problem down to the simplest example that still exhibits the issue you're trying to solve.  You'll definitely increase your odds that someone will read it and offer an answer.  As it stands, your question is a little overwhelming.

Comment: Thanks mate, I've already narrowed it down too much, explaining the problem and what I've tried